# get_user_model() returns all my users

Tags: python, django

I am trying to link only one user at a time to my model. But I am using many to many because I want to enable the option to link multiple users at a time in the future. When I run this code it assigns all my users to the Company model, I need it to assign only one. Any help will be appreciated.

**Model:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model())
    name = models.CharField(max_length=265)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('nodisoapp:home')
```

**View**

```
class CreateCompany(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    login_url = '/scrty/login/'
    form_class = forms.Companyform
    template_name = 'nodiso/create_company.html'
```

**Form**

```
class Companyform(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Company
        fields = ['name']
```

Comment: Why do you think it is assigning all users to the company model? There isn't anything in the code that is assigning users at all.

Comment: Note that the recommended way to specify the user model in a many-to-many field is `user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)`, which will avoid issues in Django < 1.11 ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, you have not included the user in the list of fields, so the `user` field shouldn't be set at all.

You could add the logged-in user to the company by overriding the `form_valid` method:

```
class CreateCompany(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    login_url = '/scrty/login/'
    form_class = forms.Companyform
    template_name = 'nodiso/create_company.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(CreateCompany, self).form_valid(form)
        self.object.user.add(self.request.user)
        return response
```

Since it's a many-to-many field, it would be less confusing to name it `users`.

Comment: I have made the changes, but it says the object has not attribute user referring to the line object.user.add(self.request.user)

Comment: Oops, that should be `self.object.user.add(...)`.

Comment: I have added the field 'user' in the form. Then the code runs without an error, but it still assigns all the users to the model exactly the same as per the original code

Comment: It's not clear why you think all users have been assigned. The original code won't assign all users, and this code won't either.

Comment: I misunderstood the admin interface, it gives a complete list of users and only highlights the assigned user, so I was thinking it is assigning all in the list.

Comment: OK, I thought that might be the problem. Glad it's working now.